# Sending mail to Active Directory group in C#

Tags: c#

Below code is used for sending mail in C#.

```
System.Web.Mail.MailMessage message=new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();
message.From="from e-mail";
message.To="to e-mail";
message.Subject="Message Subject";
message.Body="Message Body";
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer="SMTP Server Address";
System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(message);
```

But we are unable to mail to Active Directory. please help on steps that involve to sending mail to Active Directory Group.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the e-mail address for the group?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply.... here is "ContentAuthorGRP" active directory group. please provide me necessary information to send mail to AD group.

Comment: That's not an e-mail address. If you want to send an e-mail, you need the address.

Comment: Active Directory "Test@hbanc.hban.us" account.- Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Please provide me some useful information for sending mails to Active Directory from c# code.